# Has anyone ported usbmuxd library to Java?

Tags: java, ios, usb, protocols

There exists a python library for port forwarding in python for the iPhone http://marcansoft.com/blog/iphonelinux/usbmuxd/.

This library detects if any iOS device is connected to the machine and what the type of the device is. It also forwards local port of the machine to remote port.

Is anyone aware if such a library exists in Java as well?

Answer (score 1):

After looking for such an implementation for a long time and eventually implemented it myself, I can tell you with with a high degree of certainty it doesn't exist out in the open. Unfortunately I can't help with any source code (because my employers own it...), but feel free to ask any specific question.

Comment: Hello, did you use `usbmuxd` python or wrote something private in Java? I use `InetSocketAddress` -> connect but to make it work I need port forwarding. Thanks

Comment: I had two different implementations, the latest is using Netty for the entire communication layer.